# How do I find a jsp's name document?

Tags: jsp, document, named

I'm working on a web project under Struts in the IBM RAD v7.5 Websphere / Eclipse environments that has a reference in a .JSP like:
if (window.document.xyz.blah.value == ...) {.....}

I've searched the entire project and am at a loss to find how 'xyz' (where xyz is an arbitrarily created name) gets associated / assigned (or whatever appropriate term to use) to 'document'.

Where should I be looking to find this association/assignment?

Comment: Its an html form id. You've got a form in your html with `id='xyz'` and that form has a fieldname with `id='blah'`.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse :

Search >> File

Containing Text : "xyz"
File Name patterns :  * 
Scope : workspace

Would you try ?